# Can Postgres run data maintenance 'scripts'?

Tags: postgresql, performance, function, dml, amazon-aurora

In our production Aurora RDS Postgres database I need to create a new table using data from a 2 billion row source table.

I will need to use a pgplsql function to create the data for the new table.

Since every function is a transaction I assume doing this with one function call will not work.

What I am considering doing is:

1. Create a function that will create and insert a small batch of data.
2. Call the function repeatidly with a java service or lambda until all
   the data is created.
       - Unfortunately using pg_cron is not an option since it is not supported by Aurora Postgres

Creating the java service or lambda (or anything else just call the function) is something I'd like to avoid.

For our MS SQL databases we would simply run a script from SSMS that would create and commit the data in small batches in a loop.  Something similar to that doesn't seem to be an option in Postgres.

Are there any other options you can suggest?

Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: Make the "batch size" a parameter to the function. The call it with the parameter and commit after the call. But usually doing something in one large transaction is faster than many small transactions.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for commenting. I would like to do this in one big transaction but the DB will be under load from other services.  I assumed that converting 2 billion rows would take all available resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to use Powershell to repeatidly call the function using psql.

I created a postgres function that returns a status id that tells the caller if it has completed or not.  It always return a status message so the progress of the function can be tracked.

Logically the function works like this:

- create a table (if it does not exist) and populate it with metadata that controls how many times the function should be called
- read the control table to determine if any work is remaining, if no work is remaining return 0
- if work is remaining, do a batch, update the control table and return 1

This is the script and function signature:

PowerShell Script:

```
Clear-Host;
Set-Location 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin\';
$status_id = 1;
$env:PGPASSWORD = 'password';
While ($status_id -eq 1) {
    # call the function
    $results = & .\psql --% -h end-point.rds.amazonaws.com -p 5432 -U postgres -d dbname-t -q -c "select o_status_id, o_status from maint.maintainence_function();"

    # split the return value that contains a status id and an array of messages
    $status_id, $status = $results.split("|",2)

    # trim the status id so -eq can properly evaluate it
    $status_id = $status_id.Trim()

    # remove the double quote and curly braces from the array of messages.  The array of one or more messages is returned as a string in this standard postgres format:
    # {"07/18/2018 11:07:01: Message 1"}
    # {"07/18/2018 11:07:01: Message 1","07/18/2018 11:07:01: Message 2"}
    $status = $status.Replace('"','');
    $status = $status.Replace("}","");
    $status = $status.Replace("{","");
    $status = $status.Trim();

    # split the messages and output to console
    $status.Split(",");
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 2;
}
```

Postgres function signature:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION maint.maintainence_function (
    OUT o_status_id SMALLINT,
    OUT o_status VARCHAR(300)[]
)
RETURNS RECORD
AS $$
/*
RETURNS
    o_status_id
        0: SUCCESS: Function called successfully, all work is completed.  Service should NOT call function again.
        1: IN PROGRESS: Function called successfully, all work is NOT completed.  Service should call function again.
        2: Failed: Function called failed.  Service should NOT call function again.

    o_status
        Array of progress messages to be displayed in console
*/
```